# React-native-router-flux combined with react-native-side-menu issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am designing an e-commerce app using react-native (version: 0.56.0), react-native-side-menu and react-native-router-flux. When I try to go back to the initial home page by pressing the Android back button in any of the side menu screens, it is behaving weirdly (working sometimes and not working some other times). Is there a way to get ride of this issue? I don't want to use react-navigation or react-native-drawer.

Comment: Show us [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it would be helpful

Comment: Resolved this issue myself after a long research. I found "<Scene type={ActionConst.RESET} />" which did the needful for me.